# Intel Fortran error 5082 when using "include"

Tags: fortran

for a number of reasons I have to include a fixed file format, "header.f" containing only a format expression:

```
c
8000  format(/,
     &   t9,'----------------------------------------------------',/,
     &   t9,'Some header that i want to include , Tel.555-55555  ',/,
     &   t9,'----------------------------------------------------')
c
```

In my main code I have:

```
include 'header.f'
```

When compiling on Linux, with Intel compiler, I get the following message:

```
header.f(6): error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-FILE when expecting one of: <END-OF-STATEMENT> ; <LABEL> BLOCK BLOCKDATA PROGRAM MODULE TYPE COMPLEX BYTE ...
```

How should I end the header file?
Why the same example is working on Windows (using Visual Studio)? Does it depends on some compiling options?

Thank you!

EDIT 1: Obviously adding statically the code written into "header.f" into the main, works like a charm. The problem is the "compilation" of the .f containing nothing but the format.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  You can't use include to insert a fixed format source into a free format compilation.  It's possible to construct include files which work both as 72-column fixed format and free format by using both kinds of line continuation marks.

Comment: Is the main program also fixed-form?  It doesn't look like it given the lack of indentation.

Comment: I'd expect to see an error message like that if the compiler was trying to compile your `header.f` in isolation.  I think we need to know what's in the main program and how you are compiling everything.

Comment: ive seen folks try to list the include file on the compile line.. (i prefer to *not* use `.f` extension for include files just to avoid such confusion)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I'm one of the folks that include `header.f` in the compile line. The problem was that I am trying to *compile* a fixed format file used as an include.
As someone said in the comments, it's not recommendable to use `.f` extension for include files.

Lesson learned, thanks everyone for the help provided to me!